# ¿Por qué no se dice "de yo" o "de tú"?

Tags: posesivos

Me pareció muy curioso algo que apenas noté hoy. Explicaré con unos ejemplos:

> La manzana es de ella. La manzana es suya.
>
> La manzana es de nostros. La manzana es nuestra.
>
> La manzana es de ellos. La manzana es suya.

Uno podría pensar que la fórmula para los dos modelos de frases se puede generalizar:

La manzana es de **[pronombre]**. La manzana es **[posesivo]**

Pero eso no funciona para "yo" o "tú" (bueno, en mi opinión):

> La manzana es de yo [incorrecto]. La manzana es mía.
>
> La manzana es de tú [incorrecto]. La manzana es tuya.

¿Cómo se explica eso?

Comment: Se puede, aunque solo quizás con un uso más restringido, usar los pronombres, pero se usaría mí o ti (y sí, caso sea reflexivo)

Comment: Supongo que tendrá que evr con la evolución del latín, pues no es lo mismo nominativo que ablativo, aunque en español se hayan perdido los casos como tales.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

El quid de la cuestión no es que no pueda usarse **de yo* y **de tú*. Lo particular es que la primera y segunda personas del singular tienen formas pronominales tónicas de objeto (*mí* y *ti*) especiales, mientras que todas las otras personas no (porque usan las mismas formas tónicas que en la posición sujeto).

Se pueden usar *de mí* y *de ti* pero con una función diferente, no posesiva sino de procedencia (*Este regalo es de mí para ti*, por ejemplo, creo, aunque tampoco me suena del todo bien).

Sospecho que en esto puede tener que ver la distinción fundamental entre los participantes singulares de la conversación ("yo" y "tú"), por un lado, y el resto y las terceras personas, por el otro.

Comment: Sí que suena raro el ejemplo del regalo. Creería que no es gramatical. Me parece que esas formas sólo pueden darse en complementos de régimen: *No esperes nada de mí así como no espero nada de ti.*

Comment: Quizá si en vez de la cópula uso un verbo diferente: *Este regalo va de mí para ti*. Hmmm. Suena horrible de todas formas.

Comment: este caso unicamente sucede con el yo y tu dado que los indicativos de los otros pronombres son los mismos. 

incluso en con el vos y el usted